# jQuery mmenu moves page content

Tags: jquery, html, css, mmenu

I do use mmenu first time on an Project and there is one thing that isn't really working, I think it's mmenu's CSS.

Here's the URL: http://1pager.gut-entwickelt.de/

When you open the mmenu, the pages content moves a little bit. How can this be stopped?
May on your PC it works better so there's no movement, but using your iPad you will see the Problem.

Regards,
 Oliver Lippert

Comment: i can't see much movement in that page since its pretty much empty.. maybe prob is only visible on iPads then

Comment: Yes, the movement is just a little, but its moving.... :/

Comment: Could it be the default margin on the <BODY> that's making the content jump a little?

Comment: Hey Fred, thanks for the reply. It's not the margin from the body, I just updated the style.css... may you can took a further look?

Comment: The description of the issue is a bit vague: When opening the menu, the page content should move, otherwise the menu wouldn't be visible. P.S. Try adding a background-color to the body.

Answer (score 0):

I get this same issue on desktop and my iphone. For the desktop I don't really care as it's not for that but the issue is related.

On desktop - Content shifts a little.

On iphone - Make the whole page flash before sliding accross.

I guess it's something to do with the height of the content, since I tested by trial and error to remove my css and found it wasn't any of that but just some text content. If the content is short it doesn't flash.

It seems to happen with the content is greater than the browser view and shows the scrollbar, as soon as a scroll bar is required the content moves on the desktop which is the content flash on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

OK there is bug in this menu because the demo that comes with the code has this same problem when adding more content to it to increase the height. The iphone will flash the content before sliding across.

Strange thing is it doesn't happen on it's own site where it is used.